# How can I get my app to listen for Incoming SMS messages?

Tags: c#, winforms, service

I have a windows form App which is written to send and recieve texts, this is implemented by sending a message via .NET Remoting to a Service installed on a server, which has a GSM modem (dongle) connected to it, the service then sends the message through the GSM modem once it has a message from the Client App.

Everything's going well so far with regards to sending a text, However we need functionality to enable the reading of incoming text messages; I'm unsure how to go about writing my code to listen out for incoming texts, and then send them over to my Client App.

Could anyone give me some pointers on where to start please? I've tried MSDN Documentation on the TcpClientChannel Classes, but this doesn't prove useful for listening to the COM port or anything like that.

Comment: How are you sending messages? What is the interface for talking to the dongle? Unless you dongle's command set tells you if there are new messages, you will have to poll the SIM regularly for messages.

Comment: Sending messages to the Service or to the recipient? I'm talking to the dongle using AT commands through the appropriate COM port on my Physical Server, and messages are being sent to the Server through .net remoting, I.E I'm opening a TCP connection to the Server, and sending the message through a 3rd party library called GSMComm, would it be helpful to post some code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the AT command set then I'm afraid your server will have to poll the dongle's SIM for messages at an interval (whatever makes sense).

In terms or notifying the client you can either:

- follow the same scheme as the server and poll regularly

-or-

- if the remoting connection is open continuously, have the server notify using an event on one of your remoting objects. The event args for this event can contain all of the new messages.

Comment: OK great, this answers part of my question but how would I be able to receive those messages on the Client? I need to be able to receive messages and put them into a Textbox /Listbox if possible, thanks for your help so far =]

Comment: @user3661217 I believe that the bullet points answer that rest of it. If you are struggling to understand remoting or winforms, please ask another question.